# building platform specific UI (Android &Ios ) error : ,'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-io

```
Widget getPicker() {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    getDropdownButton();
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    getCupertinoPicker();
  }
}
```

error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type. i tried using return

```
Widget getPicker() {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return getDropdownButton();
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    return getCupertinoPicker();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
Widget getPicker() {
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    return getDropdownButton();
  } else {
    return getCupertinoPicker();
  }
}
```